# Test apk without compiling for each version

Tags: android, fabric-beta

If I compile my application for API level 25 and and distribute apk using fabric beta, will it automatically support other API levels? My min SDK level is set to 21.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to test, kick off some emulators and try the app with different versions, 21, 22, 23, etc and check for the results. Because sometimes the app can be installed on X version but something can do crash for a specific version.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I need to provide the apk for testing to other people. So I wanted a way to generate apks for different android api versions without changing the gradle properties each time.

Comment: Oh, no. you dont need to change nothing, if you define a minimun sdk that is the limit to run, example 21 and if you define the target as 25, that is the tools that you use to build you app, so all the version between 21 and 25  are allowed to use it. no need an apk for each version

Comment: the idea of use an emulator of each version is test if you app will run fine on each version. sometimes there's gotchas that needs to be fixed on some specific version but nothing more

Comment: I have generated the apk file and the compilesdk version is 25. If i try that apk on a device with lower api level it does not work giving package parsing error. If I change the compile sdk version it gives me all sorts of errors. I dont have developer account yet so i cannot generate the signed apk.